# Apache fop : Unable to handle if single Word in text is larger than the containing block

Tags: apache-fop

I am new to fop , will be greatful if i get help from someone...,

I am not using XSLT tranformation but creating XSLFO file directly using Java code. Everything works fine but the problem comes when particular word(long text without space) is inserted into a cell of a table-column . That bigger word is overlapping the successive block. 
  I have an fo:block element in fo:table-cell which is in fo:table-row of a fo:table. This table has 6 columns,  obviously column width is small. Now, when a **Word** in the block is larger than the block it is overlapping the next block. Give me some attribute value or any other solution to change my XSLFO file ,so that the bigger word breaks into the new line at end of the column.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The things you need to look into are:

- For the fo:table-cell: number-columns-spanned="3"
- For setting the width of fo:table-column: column-width="proportional-column-width(1.5)"

The number-columns-spanned is used as attribute of  and provides you with a means to select a bigger area where your fo:block fits.

The column-width makes it easy to define absolute width or, when using proportional-column-width, a width relative to the other columns.

I don't know of a way that lets FOP break words into multiple parts when they don't fit.